# rust: изменить путь к pdb и exe файлам

Tags: rust

В редакторе VS Code командой `rustc test_01.rs` создаются в текущей папке, например, `examples` соответствующие два файла: `test_01.pdb` и `test_01.exe`. Как изменить настройки, чтобы эти два файла создавались и *помещались в отдельную папку, например, pdb_exe* без нарушения функционала? Тогда выполнение будет командой: `.\pdb_exe\test_01.exe`. Если такое возможно, то ждать ли проблем и где в будущем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У команды `rustc` есть флаг `--out-dir`, т. е. в вашем случае надо компилировать так:

```sh
rustc test_01.rs --out-dir pdb_exe
```

И запускать:

```sh
.\pdb_exe\test_01.exe
```

Comment: да, так работает, как хотел. спасибо.